# Reference variable to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
int main() {

    int x=10;
    int *p=&x;
    int &y =*p;

    cout<< x << endl << &x <<endl;
    cout<< *p << endl << p <<endl;
    cout<< y << endl << &y <<endl;

    p++;
   *p = 20;

   cout<< x << endl << &x <<endl;
   cout<< *p << endl << p <<endl;
   cout<< y <<endl<< &y <<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Above is the code which would best explain my question. Normally, a variable reference (&) takes the address of a variable and starts referring to the same. I have tried doing the same through a pointer. I have defined a variable, pointer p points to x and a reference variable y refers to *p. Would this mean that y refers to the same variable x now?
As the next step, I stopped pointing to x through *p, what happens to reference variable y now? What would it hold. 
In the code above, cout<

Can someone help explain the behavior here.

Comment: @Pilot no, `int *const y = p`, and access syntaxes differ

Comment: @Andrey yes....ref is const pointer

Comment: `Normally, a variable reference (&) takes the address of a variable and starts referring to the same` Don't start thinking of references this way.

Comment: @Pilot: Don't start thinking of references this way. If you already started, _stop_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit can you please explain what do you mean by  already started, stop

Comment: @Pilot: Stop thinking of references as "const pointers". They are immutable, but they are not cv-qualified; in fact, it is impossible to cv-qualify a reference. And they are not pointers, even if your compiler implements them as such.

Answer (score 7):

[note: this answer is only about C++. In C, your code shouldn't compile.]

Yes, after you initialize `y`, it refers to `x`. Incrementing `p` doesn't change that -- `y` still refers to `x`.

Unfortunately, when you do the `p++; *p=20;`, you've modified `p` so it no longer refers to any allocated storage. When you write to it, you get undefined behavior. That means it's perfectly reasonable for the program to halt (or do essentially anything else).

Note, however, that incrementing `p` is entirely allowable--in this respect, `x` acts like an array of one element, and forming a pointer to one past the last element of an array is explicitly allowed. It's only when you *write* to the address that pointer refers to that you get the undefined behavior. (That is: `p++;` is fine; `*p=20;` is not).

Comment: In my machine(`gcc`) `cout<<y` is not working after `p++`, means print nothing after `p++`. Plz explain.

Comment: y should still hold 10, replace `p++;` with `p = new int;` to see

Comment: @AJ.: If you've just done `p++` (and *not* the `*p=20;`), then `cout << y;` should work fine. As soon as you do the `*p=20;`, you have undefined behavior, and there's no longer really any way to explain anything.

Answer (score 3):

```
int &y =*p;
```

is valid in C++. But in C, it is not valid and would give you compile time error.

> Would this mean that y refers to the same variable x now?

In C++, yes. But on incrementing `p`, it is no longer pointing to the variable `x` but at some un-allocated memory location. Writing to this location invokes **undefined behavior**. Now anything could happen.

Comment: As it stands right now, this answer is incorrect. Incrementing `p` so it points to un-allocated memory has behavior that's clearly defined in the standard. The undefined behavior happens only when you write to the location that pointer refers to.

Comment: it won't work because of `p++; *P .. ` you should get an error. try `p = new int;`

Comment: @haccks looked fine to me, i was just suggesting a change to OP

Answer (score 0):

There are no reference types in C. The addressof operator is **not the same** is declaring a reference in C++.

This will not compile in C:

```
int main()
{
    int j = 0;
    int& i = j;
}
```

When you do this:

```
p++;
*p = 20; // undefined behavior
```

`p` no longer points to valid memory. You must allocate memory for a pointer to point to.

In C++, if you modify `y`, it will modify `*p`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x=10;
    int *p=&x;
    int &y =*p; // y becomes a reference to x
    y = 20;
    std::cout << y << " " << *p << " " << x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the behaviour you were expecting

```
p = new int;
*p = 20;
y = *p;
```

The reference is assinged to one int - `x` . It doesn't know that you mean the one that p points to. It only knows that you wanted it to refer to the one p pointed to *when you assigned to the reference.*

Answer (score 0):

Remember that references in C++ are nothing more or less than pointers in disguise. Thus, your code

```
int x=10;
int *p=&x;
int &y =*p;

cout<< y <<endl<< &y <<endl;
p++;
*p = 20;
cout<< y <<endl<< &y <<endl;
```

is entirely equivalent to

```
int x=10;
int *p=&x;
int *y = &*p;

cout<< *y <<endl<< &*y <<endl;
p++;
*p = 20;
cout<< *y <<endl<< &*y <<endl;
```

Now, what would you expect this code to print? You neither modified y nor the value it points to, so both print statements will output the same thing.

---

Note
I left the `&*y` combination in the transformed code for clarity of how I transformed the code. Of course, `&*y` is equivalent to `y`, so a more easy to read, equivalent version would be:

```
int x=10;
int *p=&x;
int *y = p;

cout<< *y <<endl<< y <<endl;
p++;
*p = 20;
cout<< *y <<endl<< y <<endl;
```

---

Aside
In C, `&*y` is always the same as `y`, in C++ this does not need to be the case. It is in the example above. However, if `y` were of a type that overloads `operator *` (smart pointers do this), `&*y` is not equivalent to `y`. In the case of a smart pointer, `&*y` would return a naked pointer to the object the smart pointer pretents to point to.